# What is most efficient way to read a file of integer in each line without opening it?

Tags: c++

What is most efficient way to read a file of integer in each line without opening it?
I have a file with ONLY integer in each line, ie: num.txt

```
100
231 
312
...
```

In my program, I use while loop to read it;

```
int input = 0;
while(cin >> input)
{        
// Assignment
}
```

I use `time a.out <num.txt` to read it in Linux
It turns out that it will take about 15 second (**user time**) to read **100 million** numbers. So I was wondering is there any better way to decrease user time?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use iostreams if you care about performance.

Comment: Here you go:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python?rq=1

Comment: Just so you're not misleading yourself technically, you're actually using the shell to open the file when you use the redirect '<', and attaching the file to file descriptor 0, or `stdin`. If you want low-level control over exactly how the OS interacts with the file, use the bare OS calls `open(2)` and `read(2)`.

Comment: @tux3: We have, several times, shown that iostreams are pretty much identical to other methods of reading files. The only time there is a big difference is if you can map the file directly into memory. (Which most like won't work if you are feeding it through stdin) - you may have to turn of `sync_with_stdio` to  achieve reasonable performance.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm sure it's easy to find plenty of other slow methods of reading files. What I'm trying to say is that by default iostreams doesn't have great performance.

Comment: @tux3 what do you suggest as an alternative if you care about performance?

Comment: @Tux3: No, if you disable `sync_with_stdio` - at least on Linux and turn on optimisation in the compiler, `iostream` is as fast as reading large lumps of time with `fread` or `read` and parsing the integers with `strtol` or similar.

Comment: @qdii That answer by shauryachats is great imo, it's simple and reasonably fast.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I agree. Perhaps I didn't express myself very well.

Comment: Here's one discussion on speed of `fstream` (which for the purposes of this discussion is identical to `iostream`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095160/why-are-stdfstreams-so-slow/26095604#26095604
and another:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115943/what-is-the-best-efficient-way-to-read-millions-of-integers-separated-by-lines-f

Comment: I'm calling this a duplicate of the second one I just posted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int input = 0;
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
//Add this statement and see the magic!
while(cin >> input)
{        
// Assignment
}
```

To make it **ultra fast** (Not recommended for assignments!), use `getchar_unlocked()`:

```
int read_int() {
  char c = getchar_unlocked();
  while(c<'0' || c>'9') c = gc();
  int ret = 0;
  while(c>='0' && c<='9') {
    ret = 10 * ret + c - 48;
    c = getchar_unlocked();
  }
  return ret;
}

int input = 0;
while((input = read_int()) != EOF)
{        
// Assignment
}
```

Vaughn Cato's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371717/2842375) explains it beautifully.

Comment: Unbelievable! The program done in 2.5s. Can you explain the meaning of your magic code briefly please?

Comment: That would be awesome if you could explain what dangers come with deactivating `sync_with_stdio`, and why it's turned on by default.

Comment: Sure Qiaodan and @qdii I'll just add on to this.