# Linux much faster than Windows when reading data from .txt file and placing into vector. How would I speed up Windows to do the same?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, vector, stream

I have .txt files for data (100MB - 700MB). When reading these files and  placing them into vectors, Linux does this 20-30x faster. Is this a system issue, or is there something I can do to speed up Windows?

I've ran the same code hundreds of times on each system. Both systems have a 64bit compiler (without it I get a badAlloc throw).

**I've reduced the number of variables in the struct for simpler execution**

```
   struct Data //Create all possible data that would be created or imported from data.
{
    double month, day, year, hour, min, seconds, open, high, low, close, volume;
};

  vector<Data> matrix;

  void createData (ifstream &dataFile, double tick, double tickA, string name) //Imports data into program.
{
    double month, day, year, hour, min, seconds, open, high, low, close, volume;
    char delim;

    if (dataFile.is_open())
    {
        while (dataFile >> month >> delim >> day >> delim >> year >> hour >> delim >> min >> delim >> seconds >> delim >> delim >> delim >> open >> delim >> high >>
               delim >> low >> delim >> close >> delim >> volume)
        {
            matrix.push_back({month, day, year, hour, min, seconds, open, high, low, close, volume});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you use the same filesystems in windows and linux?

Comment: do you use the same optimization level on both?

Comment: What compiler and standard library are you using on Windows?  Visual C++ iostreams have some terrible performance mistakes, even worse than usual for iostreams (which are notoriously slow to begin with).  Switching to `scanf()` will get your speed back (it will probably improve the Linux version as well)

Comment: Closely related (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/15115943/103167

Comment: Debug builds or optimized builds?

Comment: Compiler version used for Linux / Windows? There can be quite some differences in performance between different versions of the std lib.

Comment: I use NTFS in Windows and ext4 in Linux. I'm using gcc 8.2.0 in Linux and MinGW 64-bit in Windows. How would scanf() get the speed back?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see  [here](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?1765-PERFORMANCE-OF-FILESYSTEMS-COMPARED-%28includes-Reiser4-and-Ext4%29.),  `ext` filesystems are much faster in read/write operation than `NTFS` so it goes  much faster on linux. so i think there is no way to make it much faster on Windows.

Comment: If I placed the .txt file in an ext4 partition, would the program read the file just as quickly in Windows?

Comment: dear @Lumbeezl, ext filesystems are not supported in windows by default, but you can install 3rd party drivers and use them, see [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/). i've not tested these tools, but it worth to try. it would speed up your program but probably not as fast as in linux.