# Writing to file line by line vs writing whole text at once

Tags: c++, file-io

I always told that file io processes are the slowest ones. However when I test the two processes below:

Scenario 1:

```
test.open("test.xml",fstream::out);
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    test<<"<p> attr1=\"test1\" attr2=\"test2\" attr3=\"test3\" attr4=\"test4\">test5</p>\n";
}
test.close();
```

Scenario 2:

```
test.open("test.xml",fstream::out);
stringstream fileDataStr;
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    fileDataStr<<"<p> attr1=\"test1\" attr2=\"test2\" attr3=\"test3\" attr4=\"test4\">test5</p>\n";
}
test<<fileDataStr;
test.close();
```

I expect the senario1 to be slower because it does 1000 file io but test result showed that it has the same speed with scenario2 (in terms of clock_t). Why this is so, is it related with OS optimization as in file read? 
[getline while reading a file vs reading whole file and then splitting based on newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463244/getline-while-reading-a-file-vs-reading-whole-file-and-then-splitting-based-on-n)

Edited: With the advice of @irW

```
  string fileDataStr;
```

changed to

```
stringstream fileDataStr;
```

Comment: Obviously because string handling is coming into picture, causing several allocations, etc

Comment: I want to do this test in equal conditions. Can I achieve this with pointers instead of using string concatenation or is there any other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way `std::ofstream` buffers output, you end up
doing exactly the same amount of IO in both cases.  (Usually,
at any rate—an implementation could optimize things when
you output a very long string.)  The only difference is that in
the second case, you've introduced an additional intermediate
buffer, which means a little more copying, and a few more
dynamic allocations.  (How many dynamic allocations depends on
the implementation, but it shouldn't be too many.)

Comment: std::ofstream buffers output and does file io when i flush or close the file(?)

Comment: @platon Or when the buffer is full.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you have `fileDataStr+=`you are making a new string and copying the previous one into it, strings are immutable! If you would use a `stringstream` it might be a more fair comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now two scenarios gives the same result (I am changing the question accordingly). Do you have an idea about this? Why stringstream is not faster?

Comment: Using `std::ostringstream` probably won't change anything; most likely, it ends up doing the same `+=` under the hood.  (Of course, it could use some sort of internal buffering, so it does it a little less frequently.  But typically `std::ostringstream` will be slower that appending to a stream.)

Comment: My guess would be that your output fstream might be doing some buffering? (not sure you should look it up) Next to that the stringstream is probably internally managed as a character array which is resized once in a while (as is the case with StringBuilder in Java) so that also causes overhead. You could eliminate the latter by reserving enough space: `str.reserve(buffersize);`

Comment: And of course, `+=` on a string doesn't make a new string.  It _will_ reallocate if the capacity isn't large enough, but this shouldn't be the case very often.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing `C++` with `Java` but `std::string` is _not_ immutable and `+=` doesn't work the way you seem to think.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer to this, because the results can and will vary with the compiler and standard library you use. For example, I put your different attempts together into a single program with a little test/timing harness. Then, just for fun, I added a fourth attempt (test3 in the code below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

static const int limit = 1000000;

void test1() {
    std::ofstream test("test.xml");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        test << "<p> attr1=\"test1\" attr2=\"test2\" attr3=\"test3\" attr4=\"test4\">test5</p>\n";
    }
    test.close();
}

void test11() {
    std::ofstream test("test.xml");
    std::string fileDataStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        fileDataStr += "<p> attr1=\"test1\" attr2=\"test2\" attr3=\"test3\" attr4=\"test4\">test5</p>\n";
    }
    test << fileDataStr;
    test.close();

}
void test2() {
    std::ofstream test("test.xml");
    std::stringstream fileDataStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        fileDataStr << "<p> attr1=\"test1\" attr2=\"test2\" attr3=\"test3\" attr4=\"test4\">test5</p>\n";
    }
    test << fileDataStr.str();
    test.close();
}

void test3() {
    std::ofstream test("test.xml");
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    char line [] = "<p> attr1=\"test1\" attr2=\"test2\" attr3=\"test3\" attr4=\"test4\">test5</p>\n";
    size_t len = strlen(line);

    buffer.reserve(limit * len + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        std::copy(line, line + len, std::back_inserter(buffer));

    test.write(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    test.close();
}

template <class T>
void timer(T f) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    f();
    clock_t stop = clock();
    std::cout << double(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds\n";
}

int main() {
    timer(test1);
    timer(test11);
    timer(test2);
    timer(test3);
}
```

Then I compiled it with VC++, and got the following results:

```
0.681 seconds
0.659 seconds
0.874 seconds
0.955 seconds
```

Then, I compiled with g++, and got these results:

```
1.267 seconds
0.725 seconds
0.795 seconds
0.649 seconds
```

The fourth version (the one I added) gives the worst performance with VC++, but the best performance with g++. The one that was next to fastest with VC++ is (by far) the slowest with g++.

You're asking why X is true. Unfortunately, X isn't consistently true at all.

We'd probably have to do pretty detailed analysis of the *exact* compiler and standard library you were using to give an answer that really meant much.